# why does a URL Link open to edit mode of SharePoint onlie list

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, online

why does a URL Link open to edit mode of SharePoint online list. i have site where u have to click a url link that should take you to another page, rather it takes you to edit mode of the list id item

Comment: please add screen shot with url details

Answer (score 0):

Check if the URL format is as follows (substituting the appropriate site URL and ID):

> http://{SiteURL}/Lists/Test/EditForm.aspx?id={ID}

**For example:**

[image]

[image]